# Running "composer install" from .cpanel.yml

Tags: cpanel, deployment, git

I have a VPS with cPanel installed.

I'm trying to run the "composer install" command from .cpanel.yml but can't get it to work.

Composer is installed on the server and called via /usr/local/bin/composer

My .cpanel.yml is as follows:

```
---
deployment:
    tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=[path]
        - composer install
        - /bin/cp -r web/* $DEPLOYPATH
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code. Composer ran but with errors.

Manually running composer and fixing the errors solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your full path to composer binary '/usr/local/bin/composer' like this:

```
deployment:
    tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=[path]
        - /usr/local/bin/composer install
        - /bin/cp -r web/* $DEPLOYPATH
```

i suggest you add some options in composer command like this:

```
deployment:
    tasks:
        - export DEPLOYPATH=[path]
        - /usr/local/bin/composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
        - /bin/cp -r web/* $DEPLOYPATH
```